# Error when serving an Angular application with Firebase Authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, npm

I’m trying to serve my Angular application, which has routing and Firebase authentication, but I’m getting this error:

> ```
> Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:15:22 - error NG6002: Appears in
> the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
>
> This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/auth) which declares AngularFireAuth 
> has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check
> if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking
> with the library’s authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
> ```

I don’t know how to solve this, since I have tried updating the library (actually, I tried updating all of them) without success. (sudo npm update).

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Issue might be related to ES2015 and possible recompilation that occur depending on Angular version and libraries. Adding versions from `package.json` and `angular.json` script level might help.

Comment: I will try modifying package.json and angular.json, just as you suggest. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, here are my angular.json and package.json files:

angular.json

```
{


"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AngularCRUD2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/AngularCRUD2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularCRUD2:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AngularCRUD2:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularCRUD2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "AngularCRUD2:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "AngularCRUD2:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "AngularCRUD2"
}
```

package.json

```
  {
  "name": "angular-crud2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9",
    "@angular/common": "9",
    "@angular/compiler": "9",
    "@angular/core": "9",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9",
    "@angular/router": "9",
    "firebase": "^8.6.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "9",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "9",
    "@angular/cli": "9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9",
    "@firebase/analytics": "^0.3.6",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

- I specified some version values to be "9" after trying the default version values.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too and it was fixed when i removed the angularfireauth import from appmodule. You only need to import it in the service or the component you need